# Deleted and recreated the branch for a pull request on GitHub. How can I reopen/push to it?

Tags: git, github

I needed to rebase and reformat the commit messages on a fork that was in a pull request. I was having issues with this, and ultimately decided to do it on another branch before doing it to the branch that is in the PR. In the process, I deleted the branch and made a new one with the same name, and the PR now closed. How can I reopen the PR, and have the PR use the newly recreated branch?

Also, the maintainers would rather not create a new PR, as it will lose the history in the previous PR

Comment: Why not just creating a new one?

Comment: The maintainers would rather not create a new PR, as it will lose the history in the previous PR

Comment: Try to push again with the original branch name and after ask to the maintainer if they can reopen the PR (not guaranteed they could. I don't know how github is coded on this subject but see nothing that could prevent it...)

Comment: @Philippe "the original branch name" – by my reading of the question, there is only a single branch name involved here.

Comment: I seem to remember you can only reopen a PR if the new branch is a direct decendent of the old one. So try something like `git branch -m my-branch out-of-way; git branch my-branch <last-sha1-before-pr-closed>; git push -f`, and then try to reopen the PR. If that worked, you can force-push the new version of your branch: `git reset --hard out-of-way; git push -f`.